# Organize/Wrap multiple divs if they contain particular

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to organize some rendered content. I'm unable to edit the original template in order to do this. Each question div will have a section number and I would like to wrap all questions that have the same number.

This is what is rendered:

```
  <div class="question">
    <div class="section-number">1</div>
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="section-number">1</div>
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="section-number">2</div>
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
    <div class="section-number">2</div>
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
```

Would like it to be something like this:

```
  <div class="section">
    <div class="question">
      <div class="section-number">1</div>
      <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <div class="section-number">1</div>
      <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="question">
      <p class="section-number">2</div>
      <div>Some Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question">
      <div class="section-number">2</div>
      <p>Some Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
var $q = $('.question');
$q.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parent('.section').length) return;

    var n = $this.children('.section-number').text();
    $q.filter(function () {
        return $(this).children('.section-number').text() === n;
    }).wrapAll('<div class="section">');
});
```

Comment: This worked great! I found that the child divs were nested deeper so I used .find()